# BigQueryML Error 80038528 what means this?

Tags: google-bigquery

I was Running BigQueryML "Create model" job, but error occurred and abort

Message :

> An internal error occurred and the request could not be completed. Error: 80038528

Code :

```
CREATE MODEL mymodel OPTIONS(MODEL_TYPE='BOOSTED_TREE_CLASSIFIER',
        -- BOOSTER_TYPE = 'GBTREE',
         AUTO_CLASS_WEIGHTS = true, 
        -- NUM_PARALLEL_TREE = 1,
        -- MAX_ITERATIONS = 50,
        -- TREE_METHOD = 'HIST',
         EARLY_STOP = FALSE,
        -- SUBSAMPLE = 0.85,
         INPUT_LABEL_COLS = ['target']) AS (
     select * from training_data )
```

Training data size less than 1GB and record count are less than 2000 rows

Please help me, someone....

Comment: Sharing your code might help others to figure out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

According to the error message in BigQuery [(link)](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/error-messages)

In case of an internalError :

1. Try the operation again later
2. Contact support.
3. File a bug. (You can find a link in the official document which I linked above.)

[image]

Comment: I looked for the error code "80038528" on the error message page, but could not find it:

Comment: @NaokiHyu  Yes. I looked for "80038528" as well but couldn't find it. But the error said it was an internal error. If it is internal, only someone who made BigQuery can look at the source and tell you. So I think it would be best to talk to Google Cloud support team.

Comment: I ran in this issue as well. I was training the BigQuery ML model using the [scripting API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting) - namely defining variables using the `DECLARE` statement.

I had no issues when training the model, but when trying to make predictions with `ML.PREDICT` I got the `80038528` you're seeing. Presumably, the BigQuery ML model does not store the actual value of the variable I'm declaring, but rather a reference that doesn't exist at the time of prediction. 

Does this describe your situation?